# Differentiation of double summation

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, summation

I am trying to figure out how to find the derivate of a double summation. The equation goes like:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (x^\top A x)$
where
$$
x = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
\vdots \\
x_n 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{and} \quad 
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \dots &a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & \dots & a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Its hard to find anything on the web about differentiation of double summation, so I hope I can get some help here!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Try the $n=2$ case and see if you can spot the pattern.

Comment: Derivative of sum is the sum of derivatives, so $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\sum_j \sum_k B_{jk} x_j x_k\right)=\sum_j \sum_k B_{jk} \frac{\partial (x_j x_k)}{\partial x_i} = \sum_j \sum_k B_{jk} (\delta_{ij} x_k + \delta_{ik} x_j)$

Comment: @SammyBlackLike this?$a_{11}x_{1}x_{1}+a_{12}x_{1}x_{2}+a_{21}x_{2}x_{1}+a_{22}x_{2}x_{2}$ if so, I don't really see any pattern..

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$A matrix can be decomposed into its symmetric and skew parts
$$\eqalign{
A_{\pm} &= \tfrac12\LR{A\pm A^T} \\
A &= A_{+} + A_{-} \\
}$$
and the value of your double sum is unchanged if $A$ is replaced with $A_+$
$$\eqalign{
x^TAx = x^TA_+x
}$$
Now consider a function which uses *different* vectors
on the left and right
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= x^TA_+y \\&= \LR{A_+y}^Tx \\
\grad{\phi}{x} &= A_+y \\
}$$
And since $A_+$ is symmetric
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= y^TA_+x \\&= \LR{A_+x}^Ty \\
\grad{\phi}{y} &= A_+x \qquad \\
}$$
If $y$ is a function of $x$ then
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\phi}{x} &= \BR{A_+y}\LR{\grad{x}{x}} + \BR{A_+x}\LR{\grad{y}{x}} \\
}$$
Finally, setting $y=x$ yields
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\LR{x^TA_+x}}{x} \;=\; 2A_+x \;=\; \LR{A+A^T}x \\
}$$